# What is the simplest and cheapest way to convert 11.1VDC battery pack to regulated 9VDC?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a portable multitrack digital recorder which I'd like to use where there's no power available for longer periods of time than regular alkaline dry cells allow. I'd like to use this 11.1 volts 4400 mAh battery pack salvaged from an old laptop. The current draw of the recorder is 200 mA.

Comment: Can you define how "regulated" you need it?

Comment: What about a LM317 or a cheap Step-Down converter from ebay or similar sites?

Answer (score 5):

To convert 11.1 V to 9V you can simply use the 7809 regulator IC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know where you found that table, but I think it is wrong. The first 7809 datasheet I checked required a minimum of 11.5V input, and I recall seeing 78-style regulator datasheets that required a minimum of 3V. (And even when the minimum was 11V, a battery voltage will drop considerably over time...)

Comment: But so will the ordinary 9V battery used by the recorder.

Comment: Here is one alternative that only drops 1V. Look for 9V LDOs in through-hole packaging. There are zillions of 78xx compatible parts with slightly different characteristics. http://www.findchips.com/avail?part=KA78R09C+ Hopefully the $1-$2 cost plus shipping isn't too much for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using a 9.1 volt zener diode and dropper resistor of 10 ohms. At 200mA, 10 ohms will drop 11.1V to 9.1V and the zener diode would just be at the edge of conduction. If the digital recorder were not drawing 200mA (let's say 1mA instead), the current into the zener would now be about 200mA.

I don't think 9.1v or probably even 9.5V would be a problem for the digital recorder but if it might be then consider using an 8.2V zener instead.

Power ratings: - the 10 ohm resistor is dropping 2V and this means its power is 400mW.

The zener when conducting 200mA will be dissipating a little under 2W so choose a 3W device or greater. It might also be worth putting a 500mA fuse in series with the series dropper resistor.

**EDITED** to make things a little clearer about its limitations: -

This circuit is simple and would work better than a standard linear regulator (given what volt-drop it would produce) but be aware that leaving the resistor and zener connected to the battery will drain the battery just as much when the digital recorder is connected.

In other words, when not using the digital recorder, disconnect the battery to sustain its charge. Also note that it is not an efficient type of regulator like a switching regulator - it dissipates power in the series resistor because, like a linear regulator, there is a voltage across input to output with the same current passing.

Comment: .. and waste more than half the battery power?

Comment: @pcj50 Simplest and cheapest and fairly inefficient too but providing the circuit is only used when the digital recorder is used its probably as efficient as a linear regulator . Let someone offer a switcher with low drop out maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think the **simplest** and **cheapest** way is you use 3 diodes like below.

11.1V - 0.7V - 0.7V - 0.7V = 9V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu7Eq5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This will work when the battery is charged to 11.1V, but as the battery discharges over time, the output voltage will also begin to drop, and so it is not regulated.  Another issue is current draw:  The output voltage will vary based on the load because of the diode's voltage drop is dependent on the forward current.

Comment: @EwokNightmares the question actually stated  easiest and cheapest, not best. If regulation is desired, this option is not good.

Comment: @Gunnish The question asks for regulated.  Also, it will not convert to 9VDC based on a lot of possible operating conditions, and it should at least be noted for this.

Comment: how about resistor divider, will it have same problem as cascaded diodes..

Comment: The resistance of the divider bottom leg has to be much less than the load since it will act as a parallel load.  This will consume lots of unnecessary current and power.  It will still suffer the same voltage drop over time since it is not regulating, just dividing.

Comment: Resistor dividers should never, ever be used to power anything; use them as crude voltage references only. For some reason this bad idea gets suggested a lot here.

Comment: @EwokNightmares you're right. But the answer using regulator was given before mine. I put this answer as an option since the question was not clear

Comment: If the 9V is nominally 6 off 1.5V alkaline cells, then the unit should handle a voltage drop to 1.2V per cell or 7.2V. With the diodes, that gives 9.3V. I would guess that the laptop battery would be flatter it's hard to say whether it would get all the charge out of it, especially since it's been salvaged from an old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

While a 7809 is a commonly available 9v regulator, most versions have a high drop-out voltage of a few volts. A drop-out is the minimum voltage between VIN and VOUT that the regulator needs to ensure that VOUT is what it should be. In this case, 11.1v battery, would not be ideal with a 7809.

A LDO like the NTE1957 would be better. At 0.5v drop-out at 1A, or 0.1v drop-out at 100mA, it would be ideal, but give 81% efficiency. You are losing 20% of power in heat.

A better solution would a switching regulator. The mc34063 is a common single chip switching regulator, that does Step Up, Step Down, and inverting. It's found in basically 80% of the usb car chargers you can buy, with all the extra parts you need (you can get them for a buck on ebay or 5 dollars retail). A simple change of a resistor or two can change the output from 5v to 9v. Typically, a R2 of 3.6k and a R1 of 1.2k are present. Replace R2 with a 7.5k resistor. Formula is Vout = 1.25 (1 + (r2/r1))

[image]